# How to deal with firebase "No auth token for request"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm using a firebase cloud storage to write files to and from a (react-native) android app, and even though my rules are on public, my device log keeps spitting out:

> W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request and W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request.

The weirdest part is that I am able to read and write files nevertheless, however my log is unreadable due to the fact that I get one of these messages every 3 milliseconds. A workaround for this would be to filter these messages out of the log file, but this would be quite a dirty way to solve the issue. Is there a different place where I should update my rules.

These are my storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete;
    }
  }
}
```

Development platform: Android API 28 with react-native, on a google pixel 2 virtual device (Google play services enabled)

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Guys, did you solve this issue? I'm facing this too! :slam:

Comment: Anyone solve this?